# Issue on for each in javascript through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code:

```
    for(i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
        for(var prop in data[i]){
            if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                element = fn.createActivityElement(prop,data[i].prop);
                $tableData.append(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where data is this this object on a .json file:

```
data = [
{
    "solved": false,
    "workStation": "",
    "procedure": "OP. 50 ATORNILLADO DE FRAME Y ENSAMBLE DE ARNES",
    "operation": "50",
    "machine": "",
    "partNumber": "738",
    "client": "VW",
    "cell": "A7",
    "activity": "Atornillado de damper a riel",
    "activityNumber": "1",
    "type": "POKA YOKE",
    "description": "2 tornillos \n 3.5 Nm +/- 0.35",
    "color" : {
        "AK1" : "#C9C9C9",
        "ZB6" : "#EFEB86",
        "DM4" : "#000000"
    }
}....
```

My for loop goes through each element(which are objects) of my array data
But then on the second loop for (var prop in data[i]) I have debuged and the issue is when I try to access:

> data[i].prop -> this give me UNDEFINED

Is weird because on data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) it gives true.

Help! please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data[i].prop` refers to the property named *prop*.

`data[i][prop]` refers to the property named by the contents of the variable `prop`.

Comment: :O you are right!
But what if I want to use "point notation" ? how can I do it?

Comment: You can't use "point notation" when using a variable to store the name of the property to access.  If you need finer control, you could use an if statement to test the name of prop before using it.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot! :D !